# Flip axes in ListPlot easy way

Tags: plotting

I have a list of data. I ploted with ListPlot but I to want flip the axes with a easy way. Instead to Plot (y,U) I want to plot (U,y).
There is some option in ListPlot?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: `ListPlot[Reverse[points, 2]]` or something like it should be useful.

Comment: Thanks! Solved.

Answer (score 3):

From the comments, an easy and efficient way to flip the axes in `ListPlot`, `ListLinePlot` and other 2D list plotting functions is to exchange the positions of the abscissa and the ordinate in the list of points:

```
points = Table[{n, n^Sin[n]}, {n, 1, 10, 0.25}];

{ListPlot[points, ImageSize -> Medium], ListPlot[Reverse[points, 2], ImageSize -> Medium]}
```

> [image: plots]

what is equivalent to

```
ListPlot[Reverse /@ points]]
```

> [image: plot]

Another method is to use `Part`:

```
ListPlot[points[[All, {2, 1}]]]
```

> [image: plot]

It is interesting that `RotateRight` (or `RotateLeft`) is more efficient than `Reverse` but the fastest one is `Part`:

```
points = Table[{n, n^Sin[n]}, {n, 1, 10, 0.0000025}];

Reverse[points, 2]; // Timing
Reverse /@ points; // Timing
RotateRight[points, {0, 1}]; // Timing
points[[All, {2, 1}]]; // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.405603, Null}
>
> {0.546004, Null}
>
> {0.171601, Null}
>
> {0.109201, Null}
> ```

```
points[[All, {2, 1}]] == RotateRight[points, {0, 1}] == Reverse[points, 2]
```

> ```
> True
> ```